# Multiple sync functions with inside async functions

Tags: javascript, angular, function, asynchronous

I have a little problem with async functions (inside functionSync1 there is an async funcion).
I have this code:

```
main() {
    functionSync1();
    functionSync2();
}

functionSync1() {
    console.log('start');
    let promise = 
    Promise.resolve(this.localStorage.getItem('myItem').toPromise());
    promise.then((val) => console.log(val));
}

functionSync2() {
    console.log('end');
}
```

For some reasons I can't modify code of `main()`, so I would like to modify `functionSync1()` in order to wait the end of the function until `console.log(val)` is executed.
Now `console.log('end')` is executed before `console.log(val)`, so the output is:

```
start
end
myItemValue
```

I need this:

```
start
myItemValue
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can't change `main`, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the output you describe using a promise queue:

```
  const queue = Promise.resolve();

  function enqueue(task, ...args) { return queue = queue.then(() => task(...args)); }

  functionSync1(){
    console.log('start');
    enqueue(() => this.localStorage.getItem('myItem').toPromise())
      .then((val) => console.log(val));
  }



  functionSync2(){
    enqueue(() => console.log('end'));
  }
```

But you should really just change `main`. Everything else is a workaround.